# What is this if-statement (in expand.grid) testing for?

Tags: r

I was looking at the source code for the `r` function `expand.grid` and noticed a command I don't understand (the last line):

```
function (..., KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) 
{
    nargs <- length(args <- list(...))
    if (!nargs)
```

I am not familiar with this syntax for an if-statement. What is  `if(!nargs)` testing? I tried testing it with something that did exist, and it worked. But it doesn't work with something that doesn't exist...

```
x <- list(1, 4, 6)
nargs <- length(x)
if(nargs)
  print("Success") #This does print "Success" and nargs exists
if(!nargs)
  print("Fail") #Doesn't print, as you'd expect    

if(!dogs) 
  print("Success") #Error: object 'dogs' not found
```

So my guess (that it was an existence test) is wrong, or I am testing it wrong.

Comment: `narg` is the length of argument list (how many arguments in the ...), so `!nargs` will be `TRUE` if `nargs==0` so if no extra argument is passed to your function

Comment: I tested that and you are correct. I don't understand why expand.grid also tests for nargs == 0L (with the same return for both) then. Or even why the if(! ) construct tests for equality to 0, not intuitive to me?

Comment: "nargs" always exists since it is assigned as the "length" of an object which is a non-negative integer; you could test how `!` behaves `!c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L)`.

Comment: But before testing how `!` behaves you should probably understand how integers are coerced to logical... try `as.logical(0:3)`.

Comment: Oh, d'oh. This is actually a really stupid question then - I forgot that behavior from R 101 because I have never needed to use it. And never understood before now when you WOULD use it. Maybe I should delete the question (not sure) (Thank you though - this is personally very helpful to me!)

Comment: @RichardScriven : "nargs" is re-assigned after the first check in `if(!nargs)`

Comment: @alexis_laz - Oh, well that's nice and confusing :)  I don't usually use reassignment.  Should have read that a little more thoroughly.

Comment: @RichardScriven : Yeah, I guess `expand.grid` starts with a confusingly compact code format - 4/5 variables created are `(n)args`...

Answer (score 1):

`!nargs` means you are testing the value of `nargs` is `FALSE` (or `0` in your case). `nargs` must exist before testing its value. In your example it does exist.

`!dogs` is trying to test a non-existing object, so you cannot test its value, `object dogs not found` is the correct error message there.

Comment: Please, try to use formatting to let others better understand what you say